# SQL server 2012: Make string fit Column Name limitations

Tags: sql-server

In my stored procedure I use string entered by the user in the application to create column names in a table. The string has no limitations in the application. Is there a way (function maybe) to convert the string so that it fits the Column Name limitations? I know that I can do `REPLACE` to remove `HTML` and special chars but I am looking for a solution that it will somehow guarantees that the converted string can be placed as Column Name.

I dont want to limit the user in the UI because the entered string can be used in other parts of the application where for example HTML chars are important

**Example:** String edited by the user: `Cat's <b>name</b>` . I wont to be converted to a valid column name string.

Comment: Instead of modifying the user input until you find something that works, why don't you ask the user for a valid column name if the first was invalid?

Comment: Validation of input begins in the user interface, not at the database level. Fix it there.

Comment: There is only one limit on a column name: it can't be more than 128 characters. Other than that, you can go crazy with it as long as you escape it: `["This," the Walrus said solemnly, "is a valid column name."]` is a valid column name, and so is `[<html><body><p><![CDATA[Hello, world!]]]]></p></body></html>]`. In T-SQL, this can be done with `QUOTENAME`. For sanity's sake, of course, you can filter it to something more reasonable for human consumption, but that's up to you (or your application's needs). SQL Server is not the limiting factor here.

Comment: I dont want to do that because the user input is used in other parts of the application. Where, for example, HTML chars are important

Comment: Then you'll have to pin down what characters you do and do not want to allow, and write a function to replace the ones you don't want to allow accordingly. SQL Server has no notion of "HTML chars".

Comment: @JeroenMostert I am doing this now by removing HTML chars and `'` but I was wondering if there was a ready made solution to limit all invalid char possibilities

Comment: Like I said -- there can't be because *there are no invalid characters* in SQL Server, and outside SQL Server, what is an "invalid character" depends on what your application *considers* invalid/cannot handle. If you want to know what characters cannot appear unescaped in a SQL Server column name, that's a different question, but a dangerous one, because there's no reason to not escape the name anyway. Relying on escaping to avoid things like SQL injection is a bad practice.